# OAuth 2.0 Client Authentication in authorization grand_type using basic auth headers not working in laravel passport

Tags: postman, basic-authentication, laravel-passport

I setup the laravel passport version 7.5 in laravel project version 5.6. when i using postman as client for test the laravel passport oauth2. after all the configuration is done. when calling oauth/token endpoints i've two options in postman as Send as basic auth header and Send client credential in body. when i use Send as basic auth header its not working and laravel throw error like client_id is missing. But when i use Send client credential in body its working perfectly.

when i use Send as basic auth header, i'm getting this error
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed.","hint":"Check the `client_id` parameter","message":"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed."}

[image]

the follow should works in both types